# ¿Cómo adquirió "pachanga" el significado de "Partido informal de fútbol"?

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos, deportes

Entre las acepciones de "[pachanga](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ROsZqkH)" según el RAE tenemos

> 1. f. Danza originaria de Cuba.
> 2. f. coloq. Alboroto, fiesta, diversión bulliciosa.
> 3. f. coloq. **Partido informal de fútbol, baloncesto u otros deportes.**
> 4. f. coloq. Arg., Cuba, El Salv., Guat., Nic. y Ur. Fiesta popular o familiar, generalmente con baile.

La segunda y tercera acepción (y por extensión la cuarta) son las que yo conocía. No sabía que una *pachanga* era de hecho un tipo de baile. Revisando la etimología de *pachanga*, [etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?pachanga) dice que la palabra "chango" hace referencia a un dios del vudú y que

> La pachanga era la fiesta para "Changó", es decir "pa'Chango", la cual finalmente se transformó el "pachanga".

Con esa etimología entiendo que `pachanga` se use para aquello relacionado con fiesta, danza, jaleo, diversión, etc. Sin embargo, "partido amistoso de fútbol o baloncesto" es forzarlo un poco. A fin de cuentas si entendemos un partido de fútbol, por muy amistoso que sea, como una danza o fiesta, ¿qué otras asociaciones no podríamos hacer de la misma manera?

¿Cómo ha llegado `pachanga` a designar a "Partido informal de fútbol, baloncesto u otros deportes"?

Comment: En Chile es **pichanga**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escarbando en el Mapa de diccionarios académicos detecté que palabra *pachanga* en sí es muy reciente. Apenas se introdujo en los años 90 del siglo XX.

No es extraño este descubrimiento, pues la palabra en sí apenas tiene 50 años de vida, tal y como se lee en [¿Por qué Pachanga es sinónimo de fiesta?](https://sabiduriadeescalera.com/por-que-pachanga-es-sinonimo-de-fiesta/):

> La pachanga surgió en Cuba cerca de 1959 como un estilo musical mezclando el son montuno y el merengue, tiene un ritmo movido y sus letras son alegres y burlonas. Se popularizó con la canción del mismo nombre que compuso Eduardo Davidsón y tocó con la orquesta Sublime.
>
> Esta canción y el furor que causó fue muy popular en Cuba, su éxito fue tal que era la música más conocida de Cuba cuando estalló la revolución. Incluso el Che Guevara describió a su movimiento como “Socialismo con pachanga”.
>
> En parte la responsabilidad del sinónimo con fiesta la tiene el escritor y premio nobel Gabriel García Márquez, quien después de un viaje a La Habana, describió a Cuba como: “una pachanga fenomenal”.

Es decir, tal y como comentas en tu enunciado, la palabra inicialmente surgió para definir un baile. Baile y Cuba se unieron para designar un acto social festivo (vals y Austria no habría provocado lo mismo, por ejemplo), que poco a poco fue ampliando su sentido hasta designar un encuentro de amigos. Lo mismo en alguno de ellos alguien sacó un balón y empezaron a jugar al fútbol, extendiendo *pachanga* a ese *partidillo* sin demasiadas reglas ni seriedad.

Encontré un blog la mar de majo llamado [*Palabra de Chile*](http://palabradechile.blogspot.com.es/). Se define como:

> Soy español, casado con una chilena. Este blog surge de los numerosos malentendidos y anécdotas por los distintos usos del idioma.

Allí hay una entrada [*Pichanga*](http://palabradechile.blogspot.com.es/2015/06/pichanga.html) en el que destaca el uso de *p**i**changa* en Chile, como [comentó Rodrigo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22922/c%C3%B3mo-adquiri%C3%B3-pachanga-el-significado-de-partido-informal-de-f%C3%BAtbol#comment36831_22922):

> Pachanga en España o pichanga en Chile, estamos hablando de un partido de fútbol, informal, entre amigos, de esos que no tienen duración, las porterías son dos rocas, o las mochilas, o los jerseys (chalecos) de los propios jugadores, con duración indefinida, generalmente hasta que el dueño de la pelota se tiene que marchar, y que en medio del partido entran, salen o cambian jugadores de equipo según las circunstancias lo aconsejen.

También encontré curioso que en 1988 el grupo Mano Negra sacara un disco llamado [*Patchanka*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patchanka), que a mi entender utilizaron como variante de *pachanga*. Para rematar, unos años después sacaron un disco en directo llamado [*In the Hell of Patchinko*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_the_Hell_of_Patchinko). Creo que es un buen símbolo de una palabra que se popularizó muy rápidamente y, a partir de allí, evolucionó de mil maneras.

Answer (score 3):

La palabra *pachanga* comenzó a circular por España en la década de los 60, como podemos ver si buscamos el término en la hemeroteca del diario ABC. Allí podemos encontrar un primer caso que habla sobre el baile:

> *"La pachanga" hace furor estos días en los salones de baile del país. Desde los tiempos del charlestón y el tango no se había visto nada igual. Un semanario escribe hoy que "la panchanga" cubana es la venganza de Castro.*
>
> ABC de Madrid, 24-5-1961, "Fidel Castro ha convertido a sus prisioneros en moneda de la guerra fría".

[Según la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pachanga_(m%C3%BAsica)), la pachanga es un tipo de baile fiestero y movido. Por tanto, no es raro que en algún momento se usara como alegoría de un estilo de juego desordenado y caótico, cuando se habla de fútbol:

> *Sobre Polonia, Suárez dijo: "Puede ser un rival interesante, ya que sus jugadores poseen técnica individual y puede haber un duelo táctico en el centro del campo, pero su estilo no tiene muchas similitudes con el de Hungría. De todas formas, no quiero que sea una pachanga y vamos a jugarlo con seriedad en todas las líneas."*
>
> ABC de Sevilla, 20-9-1989, "El zaragozista Villarroya debutará hoy en la selección absoluta frente a Polonia".

Y de ahí se pasó a usar el término para partidos de fútbol informales, en los que más que técnica y rigurosidad hay ganas de diversión, como en el baile homónimo.